# Swift 3 CoreBluetooth Background data receive

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am trying to receive some data from an Arduino which is emitting some data when I push a button.

Now I've noticed that it does not receive after a while. I did not kill the 
app yet. How come? I've already added

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>bluetooth-central</string>
    <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
    <string>external-accessory</string>
</array>
```

My devices are both paired.

EDIT:

I am trying to do the same as the [Tile App](https://www.thetileapp.com/), it works really well there.

EDIT 2:

I instantiate my manager like this:

`centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate:self, queue:nil)`

Comment: I would like to confirm if your app is in background ? and second if so, you are able to receive the data normally if the app is in foreground ?

Comment: Yes, so normally if the button on the Arduino is pressed I will turn the volume up and play a sound. That works correctly. It also works for a while when my app is in the background but on a certain moment it is just dead

Comment: Yea that is because your app has run out of its background execution time and is move to suspended state. Not sure if you have yet, but take a look at this document :  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: @Abdul91 I am checking out this part: `Apps must provide an interface that allows the user to start and stop the delivery of Bluetooth events. That interface should then open or close the session as appropriate.`. Does this literally mean that I have to have a switch which says: 'Allow sounds when app is in background'  or something like that?

Comment: Yea it does, if you have a setting screen or something similiar in your app, that would be the appropriate screen to place this switch there. Upon selecting allow on that switch your app will need to do the appropriate work to allow it to receive with BLE updates even when in suspended state.

Comment: Hello, would you provide us the code you wrote to instantiate the central manager?

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza I've updated my question!

Comment: I wrote an answer. let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: Yes thank you @GiuseppeLanza. I am currently investigating. I get the `peripheral` back in the `willRestoreState` and I am setting the delegate to the corresponding instance of the peripheral.

Comment: what problem is remaining then? Can you describe how do you perform your test?

Comment: For some reason my button does not make my app sound. I did not kill the app and it never went to battery saving mode. I got all background modes. Any other idea's? Going to post some code later on.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize your CBCentralManager by passing in the option parameter your restore key identifier.

```
let central = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: "yourkey"])
```

Where *"your key"* can be anything you want and it is useful for you just to understand that your app was awaken to handle a BLE message. If the app was killed by the system when a new BLE message will cause it to be resurrect in your app delegate didFinish launching this key will be passed in the options parameter.

To make it work properly you'll have to implement the delegate method

```
optional public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any])
```

this will be called in case of app killed by the system (or by a crash.. not by the user by the way) in order to notify you that a new BLE event happened. In the will restore state dict you will have all the info you need to restore your BLE session.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html) you will find all apple's recommendations to work with the BLE in background.

Remember that the connection with your peripheral will always be severed if the user performs any actions that voluntarily causes the connection to go off, such as app killed, Blueetooth disabled. iOS will continue to awake/resurrect your app in case of crash, app in background and then killed by the system.

The events that will cause the app to be awaken are notifications from registered notifying characteristics, new peripherals discovery, read of a characteristic. (basically any callback of the CoreBluetooth delegate)

Keep in mind that a scan operation while in background has limitations.

From apple's documentation linked before:

> Although you can perform many Bluetooth-related tasks while your app is in the background, keep in mind that scanning for peripherals while
>   your app is in the background operates differently than when your app
>   is in the foreground. In particular, when your app is scanning for
>   device while in the background:
>
> - The CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey scan option key is
>     ignored, and multiple discoveries of an advertising peripheral are
>     coalesced into a single discovery event.
> - If all apps that are scanning
>     for peripherals are in the background, the interval at which your
>     central device scans for advertising packets increases. As a result,
>     it may take longer to discover an advertising peripheral.

Happy coding.